# SQLite JDBC driver not loading on Spring Boot startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite, jdbc

I'm having an issue when deploying a .war file of a webservice using this driver (included in pom.xml and classpath) https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc

On start the webservice opens a connection with a SQLite file. Inside IntelliJ this is no issue, neither on a private virtual machine's Tomcat, but on a specific VM's Tomcat, the driver seems to fail loading. But I cannot figure out why and how to fix it.

The webservice simply saves entries in a simple SQL table.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix it?

The exception is thrown from the jdbcTemplate query here:

```
try {
    usersMovedGroupList = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlExpression,
            (resultSet, rowNum) -> new UsersMovedGroup(resultSet.getString("ump_date"), resultSet.getString("ump_user_id"), resultSet.getString("ump_user_login"), resultSet.getString("ump_group_id"), resultSet.getString("ump_group_name")));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.error("Error connecting to SQLite database : " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Here is the stackTrace :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error opening connection
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:244) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:61) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:28) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:21) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:115) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:90) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) [spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) [spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) [spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376) [spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:465) [spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:475) [spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at com.linxens.utils.AutoClearTableLog.clearTable(AutoClearTableLog.java:44) [classes/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:344) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) [spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174) [spring-web-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1911) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:825) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:475) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.50]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772) [catalina.jar:9.0.50]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.50]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.50]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library found for os.name=Windows, os.arch=x86_64, paths=[/org/sqlite/native/Windows/x86_64;C:\Tomcat 9.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Java\jre 1.8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.]
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:389) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:68) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.load(NativeDB.java:63) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:240) ~[sqlite-jdbc-3.36.0.2.jar:?]
    ... 82 more
```

Comment: _"Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library found for os.name=Windows, os.arch=x86_64, paths=[/org/sqlite/native/Windows/x86_64;C:\Tomcat 9.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Java\jre 1.8\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.]"_

Comment: Yes I've seen this, but I cannot understand why has the library is correctly download when packaging the .war

And this is only happening on a single machine (nothing found with permissions)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue. The only thing I can think of is that machine is missing some dependency (e.g. a runtime library like the MS VC++ runtime) that prevents it from loading.

Comment: Issue still occuring